# How can I reference another game in the content of my app without violating Google Play policies?

Tags: android, dependencies, google-play, google-play-console, app-update

For example, if I want to create an app with tutorials and tips for a certain game like "Weapons Guide for PUBG Mobile" or "Crafting and Positions Guide for Minecraft" or "Pokémon Go Guide", Google Play could reject the app for referencing those games in my app content and name?

I ask because Google Play once rejected the Full Description of one of my games for the simple fact of referencing the name of another game.
And if so, then how can I avoid this? since there are many unofficial apps that contain guides and tutorials for games that do not belong to them and even monetize them with ads.